# Why my pattern("yyyyMM") cannot parse with DateTimeFormatter (java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

When I using `SimpleDateFormat`, it can parse.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
format.setLenient(false);
Date d = format.parse(date);
```

But When I use Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter`,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

it throws

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '201510' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2015, MonthOfYear=10},ISO of type java
>   .time.format.Parsed

String value for date is `"201510"`.

Comment: It's not a `LocalDate` because for that you need to specify a day.  Which date should 201510 represent? The first of that month?

Comment: it works for me, compiled and run with jdk1.8.0_25

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ask yourself the question: which day should be parsed with the String `"201510"`? A `LocalDate` needs a day but since there is no day in the date to parse, an instance of `LocalDate` can't be constructed.

If you just want to parse a year and a month, you can use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object instead:

```
YearMonth localDate = YearMonth.parse(date, formatter);
```

However, if you really want to have a `LocalDate` to be parsed from this String, you can build your own `DateTimeFormatter` so that it uses the first day of the month as default value:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("yyyyMM")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                                .toFormatter();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `YearMonth` and specify the day you want (say the first for example):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
LocalDate localDate = YearMonth.parse(date, formatter).atDay(1);
```

Or if the day is irrelevant, just use a `YearMonth`.